# Displaying [Date] Value in EditorFor: No overload method for 'ToString' takes 1 argument?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datetime, razor, editorformodel

In my `INV_Assets` Model I have the following Date fields defined:

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime? acquired_date { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime? disposed_date { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime created_date { get; set; }
```

Then on my `Edit()` view I have the following `form-group`'s defined for each of these Date values:

```
<div class="form-group">
        @*@Html.LabelFor(model => model.acquired_date, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })*@
        <span class="control-label col-md-2">Acquired Date:</span>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.acquired_date, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.acquired_date, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @*@Html.LabelFor(model => model.disposed_date, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })*@
        <span class="control-label col-md-2">Disposed Date:</span>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.disposed_date, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.disposed_date, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @*@Html.LabelFor(model => model.created_date, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })*@
        <span class="control-label col-md-2">Created Date:</span>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.created_date, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @Value = Model.created_date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.created_date, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

Now then, when `created_date` has a value, I can open the form and the `EditorFor` will properly display the value. However, the `EditorFor()`'s for `acquired_date` and `disposed_date` always show up as `mm/dd/yyyy` even if there is a value saved in the Database -- if the form is saved while the editor still shows `mm/dd/yyyy` the value in database changes to `null`.

When I try to specify `acquired_date` and `disposed_date` with (Ex.) `@Value = Model.disposed_date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")` for an `htmlAttribute`, both `Model.acquired_date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")` and `Model.disposed_date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")` flag as `No overload method for 'ToString' takes 1 argument`...?

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Ideally I want to save the entered values with whatever `Date` the user specifies in the `EditorFor` and with the current `Time` at the moment of save. I then would like to display the value in format `mm/dd/yyyy` within the `EditorFor` if the user is viewing the record.

Answer (score 4):

You've got a few things going here. First, I'd assume that `EditorFor` is generating an input with type of `date`. For the HTML5 `date` input type, the provided value must be in ISO format (YYYY-MM-DD). If it's not in this format, then it's treated as if you provided no value. On post, this is then saved to your database, resulting in the null values. Long and short, you need to change your display format to:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyInEditMode = true)]
```

This is where view models come in handy, as you can have this set on the a class used for editing the object and your true desired display format set on a class used to view the object.

Second, your date properties are nullables. So you can't call `ToString` with a format directly off them. Instead, you have to do something like:

```
@Model.disposed_date.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
```

However, that will fail if the value is null, so you always need to make sure you have a value first by either wrapping it in an if block:

```
@if (Model.disposed_date.HasValue)
{
    ...
}
```

Or using a ternary:

```
@(Model.disposed_date.HasValue ? Model.disposed_date.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") : string.Empty)
```

Answer (score 1):

The format needs to be `[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]` (ISO format)

Comment: Thanks Stephen, that did the trick! Is there a simply way to go about saving the current time along with the user specified date on the control? Currently the specified date is always saved with `12:00:00 AM`.

Comment: `[DataType(DataType.Date)]` displays the browsers date picker. You can use `[DataType(DataType.DateTime)]` to display the date time picker. You can also use the technique in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27309260/populating-html5-datepicker-with-data-passed-from-a-model/27309928#27309928) but be aware that `type="date"` is not yet supported in FireFox

Comment: Hmm... when I change `DataType.Date` to `DataType.DateTime` my null value displays as an empty Editor box, and my (ex.) `created_date` displays as "2014-10-21". No Date or DateTime picker appear to be rendering?

Comment: I know there have been a few other questions regarding some inconsistent behavior regarding this. Try the solution I linked in my last comment.